# Reference the back button on UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I need a reference to the back button in the `UINavigationBar` or `UINavigationItem`. The `Back` button in the image below.

[image: Navigation Bar]

I am not customizing the button, thus

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem
```

these both are nil.

Is there any way to get a reference to the button without customizing it?

Reference:

- [backBarButtonItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/backBarButtonItem)
- [leftBarButtonItem](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationItem/leftBarButtonItem)

Update: My [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076612/reference-the-back-button-on-uinavigationbar/32076955#comment52052698_32076612) might help to understand why I don't want to customize the back button. :)

Comment: Out of interest, why do you want a reference to it?

Comment: @Phoen1xUK I am using this https://github.com/szk-atmosphere/SAHistoryNavigationViewController pod in my project. But as you can see, the discoverability of this feature is very difficult. So I am using another pod https://github.com/teodorpatras/EasyTipView to show a tip about it. Now, this tip view needs a reference to this `UIBarButtonItem` to show a tip below it.

Answer (score 6):

The [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/iad/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/ADNavigationItemClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instp/iAd.NavigationItem/backBarButtonItem) says this about the backBarButtonItem:

> When this item is the back item of the navigation bar—when it is the
>   next item below the top item—it may be represented as a back button on
>   the navigation bar. Use this property to specify the back button. The
>   default value is a button displaying the navigation item’s title.

So the `backBarButtonItem` is always `nil` by default because it belongs to the previous view controller. The only way to get a non-nil reference is by customizing it.

If you just want to change the name, however, that can be done in the previous View Controller.

Comment: This doesn't solve my issue. :( 
My use case - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076612/reference-the-back-button-on-uinavigationbar#comment52052698_32076612

Answer (score 1):

In reference to my use case - [Ayush's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32076612/reference-the-back-button-on-uinavigationbar#comment52052698_32076612)

Till the time I get a concrete solution, I have created a dummy view below the navigation bar (below the back button) to show the tip from. Here is the code.

```
let v = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 0))
view.addSubview(v)
let tipText = "Here it the back button"
EasyTipView.showAnimated(true,
  forView: v,
  withinSuperview: view,
  text:tipText,
  preferences: nil,
  delegate: self)
```

Answer (score 1):

try out this one

```
let backItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Custom Text HERE", style: .Bordered, target: nil, action: nil)
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it might help you.

```
 UINavigationItem *i = [self.navigationController.navigationBar.items firstObject];
    i.title = @"Hai";
```